# Ignore a DataMember at serialization

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, serialization

I have a WCF service and want to ignore some parts in serialization. How do I do that? I tested with IgnoreDatamember() but it did not work.

```
[DataContract(Name = "M")]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember(Name = "H"), IgnoreDataMember()]
    public MessageHeader Header { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "B")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove the complete `DataMember` attribute.